# How to manage multiple instances of the videojs using asynchronous getJSON data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, video.js

I load the JSON file list using getJSON.
My example does not work:

```
$.getJSON("https://server.com/",
    function (data) {
        var courent_id = 0;
        $.each(data, function (key, value) {
            courent_id = courent_id + 1;
            $(".video-js-tile").push("<video id='multi_video" + courent_id + "' class='video-js' controls></video>");
            var video_player = videojs('multi_video' + courent_id);
            video_player.src({
                type: "video/mp4",
                src: 'https://server.com/video/' + value.video + '.mp4'
            });
        });
        $(".video-js").each(function (videoIndex) {
            var videoId = $(this).attr("id");
            videojs(videoId).ready(function () {
                this.on("play", function (e) {
                    //pause other video
                    $(".video-js").each(function (index) {
                        if (videoIndex !== index) {
                            this.player.pause();
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    }
)
```

I can not specify the source of the video.

How to manage multiple instances of the **video.js** using asynchronous **getJSON** data?

Thank you.

Comment: you have written `$(".video-js-tile").push` but i think there is no such function in jquery. it should be `$(".video-js-tile").append`

Comment: Yes, friend! You're right, I found a mistake. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$('.videme-tile').append("<video id='tile_multiple_video" + courent_id + "' class='video-js' controls  preload='auto' width='220' height='100'></video>");
```